# Javadoc extras accepted/required by activity

Tags: android, javadoc

In my code I have some activities that **need** some extra parameters (passed as a `Bundle` in the `Intent`) to work properly. Some other need none, or have some *optional* extras.

How to document that in Javadoc?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `@param`? This only works for method parameters. It's not allowed for classes, but you can describe it in a plain text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to define `public static` method in your `Activity` to take the extra parameters and return the `Intent` that you're going to use to start your Activity.

Let's say you have an Activity called `MainActivity` and it takes an integer id and a String name. here's the code to do it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String BUNDLE_KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String BUNDLE_KEY_NAME = "name";

    /**
    * Write your documentation here
    * @param context Required to create new intent
    * @param id write description
    * @param name write description
    */
    public static Intent getIntent(Context context, int id, String name) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_KEY_ID, id);
        intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_KEY_NAME, name);
        return intent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice and clean solution, but looks a bit a walkaround. Receiving some extras and not some other, to me, looks like a property of the activity and not of one of his method. Semantically it is wrong to document this in a static method. Isn't there a method to tell javadoc "hey **this activity** has this property?"

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio ==> **Type** `/**` **above your Method Signature & Hit Enter**

Studio will create documentation basics for that particular method.

```
/**
* 
* @param args1
* @param args2
*/
private void doSomething(int args1,float args2){

}
```

You just need to add explanation.

```
/**
*  Do something will Blahhh ..Blahhh..
* @param args1 Input argument used to do Blahhh ..Blahhh..
* @param args2 Input argument used to do Blahhh ..Blahhh..
*/
private void doSomething(int args1,float args2){

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it wasn't really what I was looking for. I do know how javadoc works, but I'm searching a way to add a well formed and uniform documentation of this property of activities. Plain text looks to me not enough, but looks like javadoc has not this kind of feature.